# AmazonCloudFormation Parameter values specified for a template which does not require them

Tags: parameters, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

Im declaring a parameter named "Env" in cloudFormation template to specify deployment environment and set it default value to "dev" and i used ParamersOverrides into CodePipeline definition to change the value of the "Env" parameter for each stage, "staging " for the staging stage, "prod" for the deployment stage. the build works fine but when it comes to staging deployment i get the error shown in this image

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC7cO.png)

Here's how my Parameters section in the template looks like:

```
Parameters:
  Env:
    Type: String
    Default: dev
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - staging
      - prod
    Description: Deployment environment
```

Here's how the ParametersOverrides section in the pipeline looks like:

```
"name": "Stage",
"actions": [
    {
       "name": "Stage-Create-ChangeSet",
       "actionTypeId": {
           "category": "Deploy",
           "owner": "AWS",
           "provider": "CloudFormation",
           "version": "1"
           },
       "runOrder": 1,
       "configuration": {
           "ActionMode": "CHANGE_SET_REPLACE",
           "Capabilities": "CAPABILITY_IAM,CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM,CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND",
           "ChangeSetName": "lasco-dev-stage-changeset",
           "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::************:role/CloudFormationLascoRole",
           "StackName": "Lasco-Stage",
           "TemplatePath": "BuildArtifact::package.yml",
           "ParameterOverrides": "{\"Env\" : \"staging\"}"
       },
       "outputArtifacts": [],
       "inputArtifacts": [
           {
              "name": "BuildArtifact"
           }
       ],
       "region": "eu-west-2"
    },
    {
       "name": "Stage-Execute-ChangeSet",
       "actionTypeId": {
          "category": "Deploy",
          "owner": "AWS",
          "provider": "CloudFormation",
          "version": "1"
       },
       "runOrder": 2,
       "configuration": {
          "ActionMode": "CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE",
          "ChangeSetName": "lasco-dev-stage-changeset",
          "StackName": "Lasco-Stage"
       },
       "outputArtifacts": [],
       "inputArtifacts": [
          {
             "name": "BuildArtifact"
          }
       ],
       "region": "eu-west-2"
    },
```

Could anyone help please ?

Comment: Are you sure that `package.yml` is the correct template or its correct version?

Comment: yes, i was checking the build output artifact which is package.yml and i notice that its deleting the parameters section from cloudformation template , so at the next stage on the pipeline which is the staging deployment, cloudformation is not expecting a parameter to be overridden, i think this is why im getting that error, i dont know how to prevent this from happening when packaging the app